# Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined and Uncaught TypeError: wp.template is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, typeerror, referenceerror

I am having an issue with scripts. The scripts are preventing my images from displaying and I cannot figure out where or what I need to change to fix this? I am not sure where or what I need to edit within WordPress. Do I need to edit each file that this references?

Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined(…) wp-util.min.js?ver=4.6.1:1

at /wp-includes/js/wp-util.min.js?ver=4.6.1:1:110
at /wp-includes/js/wp-util.min.js?ver=4.6.1:1:1038​
 - (anonymous function) @ wp-util.min.js?ver=4.6.1:1
 - (anonymous function) @ wp-util.min.js?ver=4.6.1:1

```html
window.wp=window.wp||{},function(a){var b="undefined"==typeof _wpUtilSettings?{}:_wpUtilSettings;wp.template=_.memoize(function(b){var c,d={evaluate:/<#([\s\S]+?)#>/g,interpolate:/\{\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}\}/g,escape:/\{\{([^\}]+?)\}\}(?!\})/g,variable:"data"};return function(e){return(c=c||_.template(a("#tmpl-"+b).html(),d))(e)}}),wp.ajax={settings:b.ajax||{},post:function(a,b){return wp.ajax.send({data:_.isObject(a)?a:_.extend(b||{},{action:a})})},send:function(b,c){var d,e;return _.isObject(b)?c=b:(c=c||{},c.data=_.extend(c.data||{},{action:b})),c=_.defaults(c||{},{type:"POST",url:wp.ajax.settings.url,context:this}),e=a.Deferred(function(b){c.success&&b.done(c.success),c.error&&b.fail(c.error),delete c.success,delete c.error,b.jqXHR=a.ajax(c).done(function(a){"1"!==a&&1!==a||(a={success:!0}),_.isObject(a)&&!_.isUndefined(a.success)?b[a.success?"resolveWith":"rejectWith"](this,[a.data]):b.rejectWith(this,[a])}).fail(function(){b.rejectWith(this,arguments)})}),d=e.promise(),d.abort=function(){return e.jqXHR.abort(),this},d}}}(jQuery);
```

Uncaught TypeError: wp.template is not a function(…) add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.6.8:4**

at a.fn.init.a.fn.wc_variation_form ( /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.6.8:4:235)

at HTMLFormElement. ( /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.6.8:4:8427)

at Function.each ( /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2:2881)

at a.fn.init.each ( /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2:846)

at HTMLDocument. ( /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.6.8:4:8403)

at i ( /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2:27449)

at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] ( /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2:28213)

at Function.ready ( /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2:30006)

at HTMLDocument.K ( /wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2:30368)

- a.fn.wc_variation_form @ add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.6.8:4
- (anonymous function) @ add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.6.8:4
- each @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2 each @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
- (anonymous function) @ add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.6.8:4
- i @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2fire With @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
- ready @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2 K @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2

```html
/*!
 * Variations Plugin
 */
!function(a,b,c,d){a.fn.wc_variation_form=function(){var c=this,d=c.find(".single_variation"),f=c.closest(".product"),g=parseInt(c.data("product_id"),10),h=c.data("product_variations"),i=h===!1,j=!1,k=c.find(".reset_variations"),l=wp.template("variation-template"),m=wp.template("unavailable-variation-template"),n=c.find(".single_variation_wrap");return n.show(),c.unbind("check_variations update_variation_values found_variation"),c.find(".reset_variations").unbind("click"),c.find(".variations select").unbind("change focusin"),c.on("click",".reset_variations",function(a){a.preventDefault(),c.find(".variations select").val("").change(),c.trigger("reset_data")}).on("hide_variation",function(a){a.preventDefault(),c.find(".single_add_to_cart_button").removeClass("wc-variation-is-unavailable").addClass("disabled wc-variation-selection-needed"),c.find(".woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart").removeClass("woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled").addClass("woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled")}).on("show_variation",function(a,b,d){a.preventDefault(),d?(c.find(".single_add_to_cart_button").removeClass("disabled wc-variation-selection-needed wc-variation-is-unavailable"),c.find(".woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart").removeClass("woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled").addClass("woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled")):(c.find(".single_add_to_cart_button").removeClass("wc-variation-selection-needed").addClass("disabled wc-variation-is-unavailable"),c.find(".woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart").removeClass("woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled").addClass("woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled"))}).on("click",".single_add_to_cart_button",function(c){var d=a(this);d.is(".disabled")&&(c.preventDefault(),d.is(".wc-variation-is-unavailable")?b.alert(wc_add_to_cart_variation_params.i18n_unavailable_text):d.is(".wc-variation-selection-needed")&&b.alert(wc_add_to_cart_variation_params.i18n_make_a_selection_text))}).on("reload_product_variations",function(){h=c.data("product_variations"),i=h===!1}).on("reset_data",function(){f.find(".product_meta").find(".sku").wc_reset_content(),a(".product_weight").wc_reset_content(),a(".product_dimensions").wc_reset_content(),c.trigger("reset_image"),d.slideUp(200).trigger("hide_variation")}).on("reset_image",function(){c.wc_variations_image_update(!1)}).on("change",".variations select",function(){if(c.find('input[name="variation_id"], input.variation_id').val("").change(),c.find(".wc-no-matching-variations").remove(),i){j&&j.abort();var b=!0,d=!1,e={};c.find(".variations select").each(function(){var c=a(this).data("attribute_name")||a(this).attr("name"),f=a(this).val()||"";0===f.length?b=!1:d=!0,e[c]=f}),b?(e.product_id=g,e.custom_data=c.data("custom_data"),c.block({message:null,overlayCSS:{background:"#fff",opacity:.6}}),j=a.ajax({url:wc_cart_fragments_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace("%%endpoint%%","get_variation"),type:"POST",data:e,success:function(a){a?c.trigger("found_variation",[a]):(c.trigger("reset_data"),c.find(".single_variation").after('<p class="wc-no-matching-variations woocommerce-info">'+wc_add_to_cart_variation_params.i18n_no_matching_variations_text+"</p>"),c.find(".wc-no-matching-variations").slideDown(200))},complete:function(){c.unblock()}})):c.trigger("reset_data"),d?"hidden"===k.css("visibility")&&k.css("visibility","visible").hide().fadeIn():k.css("visibility","hidden")}else c.trigger("woocommerce_variation_select_change"),c.trigger("check_variations",["",!1]),a(this).blur();a(".product.has-default-attributes > .images").fadeTo(200,1),c.trigger("woocommerce_variation_has_changed")}).on("focusin touchstart",".variations select",function(){a(this).find("option:selected").attr("selected","selected"),i||(c.trigger("woocommerce_variation_select_focusin"),c.trigger("check_variations",[a(this).data("attribute_name")||a(this).attr("name"),!0]))}).on("found_variation",function(b,e){var g=f.find(".product_meta").find(".sku"),h=f.find(".product_weight"),i=f.find(".product_dimensions"),j=n.find(".quantity"),k=!0;e.sku?g.wc_set_content(e.sku):g.wc_reset_content(),e.weight?h.wc_set_content(e.weight):h.wc_reset_content(),e.dimensions?i.wc_set_content(e.dimensions):i.wc_reset_content(),c.wc_variations_image_update(e);var o="";e.variation_is_visible?(o=l({variation:e}),o=o.replace("/*<![CDATA[*/",""),o=o.replace("/*]]>*/",""),d.html(o),c.find('input[name="variation_id"], input.variation_id').val(e.variation_id).change()):(o=m(),o=o.replace("/*<![CDATA[*/",""),o=o.replace("/*]]>*/",""),d.html(o),c.find('input[name="variation_id"], input.variation_id').val("").change()),"yes"===e.is_sold_individually?(j.find("input.qty").val("1").attr("min","1").attr("max",""),j.hide()):(j.find("input.qty").attr("min",e.min_qty).attr("max",e.max_qty),j.show()),e.is_purchasable&&e.is_in_stock&&e.variation_is_visible||(k=!1),a.trim(d.text())?d.slideDown(200).trigger("show_variation",[e,k]):d.show().trigger("show_variation",[e,k])}).on("check_variations",function(c,f,g){if(!i){var j=!0,k=!1,l={},m=a(this),n=m.find(".reset_variations");m.find(".variations select").each(function(){var b=a(this).data("attribute_name")||a(this).attr("name"),c=a(this).val()||"";0===c.length?j=!1:k=!0,f&&b===f?(j=!1,l[b]=""):l[b]=c});var o=e.find_matching_variations(h,l);if(j){var p=o.shift();p?m.trigger("found_variation",[p]):(m.find(".variations select").val(""),g||m.trigger("reset_data"),b.alert(wc_add_to_cart_variation_params.i18n_no_matching_variations_text))}else m.trigger("update_variation_values",[o]),g||m.trigger("reset_data"),f||d.slideUp(200).trigger("hide_variation");k?"hidden"===n.css("visibility")&&n.css("visibility","visible").hide().fadeIn():n.css("visibility","hidden")}}).on("update_variation_values",function(b,d){i||(c.find(".variations select").each(function(b,c){var e,f=a(c),g=a(c).data("show_option_none"),h="no"===g?"":":gt(0)";f.data("attribute_options")||f.data("attribute_options",f.find("option"+h).get()),f.find("option"+h).remove(),f.append(f.data("attribute_options")),f.find("option"+h).removeClass("attached"),f.find("option"+h).removeClass("enabled"),f.find("option"+h).removeAttr("disabled"),e="undefined"!=typeof f.data("attribute_name")?f.data("attribute_name"):f.attr("name");for(var i in d)if("undefined"!=typeof d[i]){var j=d[i].attributes;for(var k in j)if(j.hasOwnProperty(k)){var l=j[k];if(k===e){var m="";d[i].variation_is_active&&(m="enabled"),l?(l=a("<div/>").html(l).text(),l=l.replace(/'/g,"\\'"),l=l.replace(/"/g,'\\"'),f.find('option[value="'+l+'"]').addClass("attached "+m)):f.find("option"+h).addClass("attached "+m)}}}f.find("option"+h+":not(.attached)").remove(),f.find("option"+h+":not(.enabled)").attr("disabled","disabled")}),c.trigger("woocommerce_update_variation_values"))}),c.trigger("wc_variation_form"),c};var e={find_matching_variations:function(a,b){for(var c=[],d=0;d<a.length;d++){var f=a[d];e.variations_match(f.attributes,b)&&c.push(f)}return c},variations_match:function(a,b){var c=!0;for(var e in a)if(a.hasOwnProperty(e)){var f=a[e],g=b[e];f!==d&&g!==d&&0!==f.length&&0!==g.length&&f!==g&&(c=!1)}return c}};a.fn.wc_set_content=function(a){d===this.attr("data-o_content")&&this.attr("data-o_content",this.text()),this.text(a)},a.fn.wc_reset_content=function(){d!==this.attr("data-o_content")&&this.text(this.attr("data-o_content"))},a.fn.wc_set_variation_attr=function(a,b){d===this.attr("data-o_"+a)&&this.attr("data-o_"+a,this.attr(a)?this.attr(a):""),this.attr(a,b)},a.fn.wc_reset_variation_attr=function(a){d!==this.attr("data-o_"+a)&&this.attr(a,this.attr("data-o_"+a))},a.fn.wc_variations_image_update=function(a){var b=this,c=b.closest(".product"),d=c.find("div.images img:eq(0)"),e=c.find("div.images a.zoom:eq(0)");a&&a.image_src&&a.image_src.length>1?(d.wc_set_variation_attr("src",a.image_src),d.wc_set_variation_attr("title",a.image_title),d.wc_set_variation_attr("alt",a.image_alt),d.wc_set_variation_attr("srcset",a.image_srcset),d.wc_set_variation_attr("sizes",a.image_sizes),e.wc_set_variation_attr("href",a.image_link),e.wc_set_variation_attr("title",a.image_caption)):(d.wc_reset_variation_attr("src"),d.wc_reset_variation_attr("title"),d.wc_reset_variation_attr("alt"),d.wc_reset_variation_attr("srcset"),d.wc_reset_variation_attr("sizes"),e.wc_reset_variation_attr("href"),e.wc_reset_variation_attr("title"))},a(function(){"undefined"!=typeof wc_add_to_cart_variation_params&&a(".variations_form").each(function(){a(this).wc_variation_form().find(".variations select:eq(0)").change()})})}(jQuery,window,document);
```

Comment: You need to add `underscore.js` for this.

Comment: Where do I add this script?

Comment: In the theme's source.

Comment: I am still having the same issue. Maybe you are just referring to answering the first part of the question. There are two types of errors. Is your answer saying that it will fix both?

Comment: I updated to reflect coding of file